# Integrating tornado (4.4.1), sqlalchemy (1.1.0) and alembic (0.8.7) in Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, tornado, alembic

I am writing my first Python web application, and I want to use alembic for handling the migrations. So far I have done this (just pointing out the imp. files) and it doesn't seem to work.

Project structure:

```
project/
    alembic.ini
    alembic/
        versions/
            3cd4a4f9cdef_create_users_table.py
    models/
        __init__.py
        base.py
        users.py
```

3cd4a4f9cdef_create_users_table.py

```
"""create users table

Revision ID: 3cd4a4f9cdef
Revises:
Create Date: 2016-09-07 13:54:25.705084

"""

# revision identifiers, used by Alembic.
revision = '3cd4a4f9cdef'
down_revision = None
branch_labels = None
depends_on = None

from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa


def upgrade():
    op.create_table(
        'users',
        Column('id', sa.Integer, primary_key=True),
        Column('name', sa.String(256), nullable=False)
    )


def downgrade():
    op.drop_table('users')
```

__init__.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.sql import select
from users import User

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///:memory:', echo=True)
```

base.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

Base = declarative_base()
```

users.py

```
from base import Base

class User(Base):

    user_table = 'users'
    __table__ = user_table

    id = user_table.c.id
    name = user_table.c.name
```

`$ python models/__init__.py` throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "models/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from users import User
  File "/Users/sudeep.agarwal/src/project/models/users.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Asset(Base):
  File "/Users/sudeep.agarwal/src/squiddy/models/users.py", line 10, in Asset
    id = asset_table.c.id
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'c'
```

I don't want to do this in users.py as it would mean duplication of schema definition:

```
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column

class User(Base):

    __table__ = 'users'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String, nullable=False)
```

What is the cleanest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Frankly, I do not quite understand what you're trying to do. But some parts of code looks completely wrong. Why have you two definitions of `User`? What are you trying to achieve with `id = user_table.c.id`? I can only guess. At first, define somewhere table schema:

```
metadata = MetaData()
users_schema = Table('users', metadata,
    Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column('name', String, nullable=False)
)
```

Then you can use it to define the model:

```
class User(Base):
    __table__ = users_schema
```

Or you can define the model directly:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = Column('id', Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column('name', String, nullable=False)
```

And you do not need to redefine it in other files. Only import it and use.

Comment: Hey, thanks. I changed the code to the first method (using user_schema variable) you suggested and am using alembic's autogenerate switch to generate migrations. Works like a charm now.